# Мне нужно установить ретро лямбду означает ли это, что всем нужно установить jdk8?

Tags: java, android

Я хочу попробовать использовать ретро лямбду в проекте

https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

означает ли это, что все разработчики участвующие в проекте должны обновить jdk до 8 версии?

Так как ретро лябда требует это

Comment: Если вы добавляете зависимость, которая требует jdk 8, в общий проект, то логично, что всем, кто в нем участвует, придется ее ставить

Comment: @rjhdby я подумал может я что то недопонял... Тогда это не совсем удобно=( хотел попробовать ее в проекте, но не удобно получается напрягать всех, чтоб ее ставили

Comment: Не, ну в отдельном бранче то никто не мешает

Comment: @rjhdby ну ясно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первой строкой в разделе об использовании этой библиотеки идёт:

> Download jdk8 and set it as your default.

Думаю, этим всё сказано.